# menu opens wrong activity

Tags: android, menu

My problem is when i click programmer it open twitter !

{see the end of main java ; this is my menu}

when I click twitter on emulator, it opens programmer, and the reverse is true.

where is the problem ?

main java

```
package com.rum.city;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;



public class myMenu extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);




Button bt_about = (Button) findViewById(R.id.about);
bt_about.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(myMenu.this, about.class));

        }
   });




Button bt_blocks = (Button) findViewById(R.id.blocks);
bt_blocks.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(myMenu.this, blocks.class));

        }
   });



Button bt_hosay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hosay);
bt_hosay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(View v)
        {

            startActivity(new Intent(myMenu.this, hosay.class));
        }
});



Button bt_stati = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stati);
bt_stati.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
{
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(myMenu.this, stati.class));

        }
   });
       }



public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
MenuInflater awesome = getMenuInflater();
awesome.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
return true;
     }
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menunews:
        String url = "http://j.mp/rumnw";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
        return true;

        case R.id.menutwitter:
        String rb6 = "https://twitter.com/#!/Rum_City";
        Intent r = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        r.setData(Uri.parse(rb6));
        startActivity(r);
        return true;

        case R.id.menuhwl:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.rum.city.HWL"));
        return true;

    }

    return false;
    }
}
```

menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
/>
<item 
android:id="@+id/menunews"
android:alphabeticShortcut="s"
android:title="news"   
/>    


    <item 
android:id="@+id/menutwitter"
android:alphabeticShortcut="t"
android:title="twitter"   
/>
    <item 
android:id="@+id/menuhwl"
android:title="programmer"
android:alphabeticShortcut="a">
</item>
```

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger to see when the twitter case is being reached? Nothing looks wrong, or rather, incorrectly wired, in the code you posted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you recently change the ids ? Sometime the IDE gets mixed up and confuses ID.
The way around this is to clean the project & rebuild.

Comment: Thank you guys for your attention, no thing worked, so i deleted the whole menu and it's code on main java and re wrote it

Comment: Great! Every menu action was totally messed up, and now it's working again! Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()){
    case R.id.menunews:
        String url = "http://j.mp/rumnw";
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
        startActivity(i);
         break;

        case R.id.menutwitter:
        String rb6 = "https://twitter.com/#!/Rum_City";
        Intent r = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        r.setData(Uri.parse(rb6));
        startActivity(r);
        break;

        case R.id.menuhwl:
            startActivity(new Intent("com.rum.city.HWL"));
      break;

    }


    }
return true;
}
```

Comment: instead of return use break and try